# Coverting Vector to Border Expression Blend

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

I am using expression blend to build a window for a Windows Presentation Foundation application. I have a vector that I want to covert to a border and I have absolutely no idea how I can do that.

Comment: I guess not many people will actually have an idea how to convert a Vector into a Border, as these are two completely unrelated concepts. Could you please explain why you would do this? Are you perhaps trying to use the Vector's X and Y values as kind of a border width?

Comment: 1) use import from psd into expression blend.
2) then after import was successful right click on path and Make Into Control  (of type border of course)
Have a look at this : http://visitmix.com/labs/rosetta/EyesOfBlend/Import/